# PHP/MYSQL - Mysqli Prepared Statements - Fetch table data and add each row to a local array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

I have a list of various postal information. This data is within a mysql table called "postal_codes".

I would like to add each row of this table into a local array for use in a script.

The problemt hat I am facing is that I keep getting errors relating to undefined variables within the while loop.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// Get postal info and make into array
$postalCodes[] = array();
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT id, suburb, boxCode, streetCode, townName FROM postal_codes")) {

    if (!$stmt->execute())
    {
        printf("failed to execute");
    }
    if (!$stmt->bind_result($id, $suburb, $boxCode, $streetCode, $townName))
    {
        printf("failed to bind params");
    }
    if (!$stmt->store_result())
    {
        printf("failed to store result");
    }
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $postalCodes['id'] += $id;
        $postalCodes['suburb'] += $suburb;
        $postalCodes['boxCode'] += $boxCode;
        $postalCodes['streetCode'] += $streetCode;
        $postalCodes['townName'] += $townName;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

foreach ($postalCodes as $postalCode)
{
    if ($postalCode['boxCode'] == 5850)
    {
        printf("{$postalCode['suburb']}");
    }
}
```

Could someone by chance spot the problem with this code or suggest a way for me to code this procedure in a better way.

Any assistance and insight in this regard would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: so you just need to copy the results into an array right?

Comment: Why are you using += I cant understand why you'd want to add some of these values

Comment: @BlackberryFan can you post the actual error that you're getting.

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\includes\admin\users.html.php on line 23` line 23 is `$postalCodes['id'] += $id;` I get the same error for each line in the while loop.

Comment: The main thing here is the "+=" operator. A simple assignment ("=") would not cause a warning. But the "+=" is equal to $x = $x + $y, which means it tries to access the current value before adding to it. That said, this will not get you a 2d array if that's what you're looking for (it'll just add the numeric values and i don't know what it'll do to strings). Use $postalCodes['id'][] = $id;

Comment: @Pinetree Makes perfect sense but how would I call the value in my foreach row then?

Comment: Oh, after another look, what you should actually do is add values to $postalCodes (in the while loop) like this:

$postalCodes[] = array("id" => $id, "suburb" => $suburb, ...); 

What i've suggested before ($postalCodes["key"][]) would actualy turn the array, so you'd have all ids, all suburbs and other values as individual arrays.

Comment: @Pinetree thank you that was spot on! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Btw, could you switch to PDO? Pdo statemtent has the fetchAll() method, which would give you the result set as a two dimentional array where every inner array maps to a row in the result set.
[PDO::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: @Pinetree Thank you friend but im afraid that is over my head at the moment... Just trying to come to grips with mysqli :) One day though... Sounds very cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "error" is probably caused by your associative array:

```
$postalCodes['id'] += $id;
```

Ask yourself: what is the value of `$postalCodes['id']` the first time you call this? It still isn't defined. So you can either initialize the variables beforehand, or you can switch off warnings of this type through [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).

**EDIT: The array-issue**

You want to do something like:

```
$postalCodes=array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $postalCodes[] = array('id' => $id,
        'suburb' => $suburb,
        'boxCode' => $boxCode,
        'streetCode' => $streetCode,
        'townName' => $townName);
}
foreach($postalCodes as $postalCode) {
    // do whatever you need to do
    // with the associative array, e.g.
    echo $postcalCode['boxCode'];
}
```

I think you were confused about the meaning of `+=`. If you want to add an element to your array, you use `array[]=something`.

Comment: Thanks but i would have thought that the first line `$postalCodes[] = array();` would have opened these values? And my site is still in development, hence the error reporting. but even still, no result is displayed as it should be.

Comment: Okay thanks for the link, how would I initialize the variables correctly?

Comment: Or to give you the quote that matters: "Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable: an E_NOTICE-level error message will be issued, and the result will be NULL."

Comment: You could turn the "+=" into a simple "="? I am not sure why you are trying to add these results together? Or are you looking to get a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Arrays confuse me :) As in the latter part of the code, I would like functionality of that nature. Is it even possible or is my logic flawed in this?

Comment: @Pinetree Alright I see that you are saying... `+=` is like saying add value B to value A? Like 1 + 3 = 4

Comment: okay with the + removed I now get `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\includes\admin\users.html.php on line 34` this is the foreach line... there Is another error stating that boxCode is undefined

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT id, suburb, boxCode, streetCode, townName FROM postal_codes"))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $suburb, $boxCode, $streetCode, $townName);
    $stmt->store_result();
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $postalCodes[] = array("id" => $id, "suburb" => $suburb, "boxCode" => $boxCode, "streetCode" => $streetCode, "townName" => $townName);
    }
}
```

I didn't notice that you were actually using prepared statements in mysqli. I've modified my answer to utilize prepared statements.

Comment: I have used `bind_result` to fetch these variables. I am looking for a solution that works with this function, out of interest sake for the time being.

Comment: Okay that is pretty much what I have now, but you must do `store_result` before fetching it? Also, how would I then call the values within the foreach loop?

Comment: It would help if you print_r($postalCodes); and edit your question. I'm not yet fluent enough in php that I can guess how you would fetch the values from foreach. So yeah include the output of print_r($postalCodes) in your question or just comment it here.

Comment: The problem is that there are 17000 rows :) if i do print f my computer might pop, but let get a short output for you

Comment: @BlackberryFan: put LIMIT 5 in your query

Comment: `Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [suburb] => Array ( [0] => TEST SUBURB ) [boxCode] => Array ( [0] => 5850 ) [streetCode] => Array ( [0] => 5851 ) [townName] => Array ( [0] => TEST TOWN ) ) ` This is the output for one line

Comment: Please see the comment in my op from pine tree. This is the correct approach in this.

Comment: BlackberryFan: See my edit below, that's how you want to construct the array.